# Should there be Fogbugz ads on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Or maybe they're already here (my company's firewall blocks most ads, so I don't see many of them).

But since you've admitted that there's extra ad inventory, that would seem like a natural fit to fill in some of it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the only problem would be if you start adding FogBugz ads, you aren't actually generating ad revenue, you are attempting to use your ad revenue generating space to try and generate other revenue (unless Joel actually pays to have his own ads on a site he helped found).

Naturally I think advertising for their products would be logical, but I could also see why you wouldn't want to potentially cut out other advertisers from paying to actually use that space.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using one product to drive sales to another.

Comment: I'm not saying there is anything wrong at all. I agree that it would seem logical to do so. I am just wondering if the reason they are NOT doing so is because of the difference between ad revenue and potential sale revenue, that's all. I think an interesting idea would be for StackOverflow to possibly have a separate area (sort of like the jobs board) where the different products from Fog Creek and the like are showcased. Sort of separating the ad-revenue generating space from the sales revenue space. Or maybe I am just thinking about this way too much and I need some more caffeine.

Comment: Nah: I'm only talking about using these ads as filler when they don't sell out of other stuff.  I think it likely has more to do that Joel want's to keep bragging that he's always only relied on word of mouth marketing.

Comment: If it is just used as filler than sure. I have no idea what the demand is for ad space on these sites, so I wasn't certain. If Joel wants to stick to that route, so be it. Might be why I had never heard of FogBugz until I started using these sites (I was never a follower of either blog).

Comment: ♦ discussion!!!

Answer (score 0):

FogBugz is a Product of FogCreek, the StackOverflow family of sites is a product of StackOverflow.com LLC.

Essentially two different companies (even though StackExchange makes their relationship a bit blurry), and I doubt that Jeff gets money for FogBugz sales. So realistically, FogCreek would have to pay money to StackOverflow.com LLC, so for them it boils down to the question: "Is it worth advertising FogBugz on StackOverflow?", and I assume that question either never came up or was answered negatively.

I think that advertising for StackExchange would be more logical than for FogBugz, but I assume they will come as soon as SE is out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

If FogCreek is willing to pay for the ad space, I don't see why not.

And I think that it would be best if FogCreek did pay for ad space if they wanted it. Otherwise, other vendors of bug tracking solutions may raise a cry about preferential treatment.